# Use NSPredicates/KVC to grab an array of sibling keys

Tags: iphone, cocoa, ios, nspredicate, key-value-coding

Another way to word this might be...

```
NSPredicate "state.country == 'United States'"
```

is like

```
SQL "Select * from state where state.country = 'United States'
```

so how do I do this as a predicate?

```
SQL "Select state.name from state where state.county = 'United States'"
```

ORIGINAL POST:

I have a dictionary of arrays of dictionaries that looks like this:

```
lists
  states
    state
    country
  country
    country
```

I have code to filter states by country.  However, I'm betting there is a cleaner way.

```
NSArray *states = [lists valueForKey:@"states"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"countryname == %@", selectedCountry];
states = [states filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
states = [states valueForKeyPath:@"state"];
```

Ideas?

Comment: I may be missing something obvious, but your structural diagram makes absolutely no sense to me.  Can you give a concrete example?

Comment: he wants to get the state of a given country-name. He searches for Cupertino and gets California, am I right?

Comment: Yes.  

States have a name and a country string.   Obtain a list of states who have state.country == "United States".  State class has state.state, state.country.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've almost got it:

```
NSDictionary * lists = ...;
```

This is your original dictionaryl

```
NSArray *states = [lists objectForKey:@"states"];
```

This is to retrieve the array of states from your dictionary.  Presumably these are actual "State" objects (ie, you made a class called `State`)

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"countryname == %@", selectedCountry];
```

This creates a predicate that will compare the results of `-[State countryname]` to the value referenced by the `selectedCountry` variable.  Alternatively, if the `states` array contains dictionaries, this will compare the results of `-[NSDictionary objectForKey:@"countryname"]` to the value referenced by `selectedCountry`.

```
states = [states filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

This will retrieve all the states from the array where `[[aState countryname] isEqual:selectedCountry]`

```
states = [states valueForKeyPath:@"name"];
```

This will create a new array that contains the name of each state.  This new array will be in the same order as your filtered `states` array.

Comment: It looks like this is the cleanest way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm only using NSArray and not NSDictionary so I don't know how useful this is but I'm using this:

```
matchingTour = [self.tours filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tourCode == %@", tourCode]];
```

where self.tours is an NSArray of Tour objects. A Tour object has a property of NSString *tourCode. matchingTour is of type NSArray.

I was amazed when I read about this, tried it and it worked first time and I got back an array containing just the one tour!

In your 'tree' you don't show any property name 'countryname' - just wondering.